# SQL Server: Consolidate the result into a single row

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data result.

```
Name      Shift   Station   0-4 Hrs    5-12 Hrs    13-18 Hrs    19-24 Hrs   TotalPayAmount
John Doe   A       02        1           0           0             0             0
John Doe   A       02        0           1           0             0             15
John Doe   A       02        0           0           1             0             20
```

I need the result to look like this.

```
Name      Shift   Station   0-4 Hrs    5-12 Hrs    13-18 Hrs    19-24 Hrs   TotalPayAmount
John Doe   A       02        1           1           1             0             35
```

I think I have to use the PIVOT function, but I just do not know how to.

Here is the SQL query with an example user "John Doe", but there are many users.

```
select s.name
,s.shift
,s.station
,case
when t.WorkHours <= 4 then count(*) else 0
end as '0-4Hrs'
,case 
when t.WorkHours >= 5 and t.WorkHours <= 12 then count(*) else 0
end as '5-12Hrs'
,case 
when t.WorkHours >= 13 and t.WorkHours <= 18 then count(*) else 0
end as '13-18Hrs'
,case
when t.WorkHours >= 19 and t.WorkHours <=24 then count(*) else 0
end as '19-24Hrs'
,sum(p.PayRate) as TotalPayAmount
from staff s
left join Time t on t.FSID = s.FSID
left join Pay p on p.Hours = t.WorkHours
where s.name = 'John Doe'
group by  s.name, s.shift, s.station, t.WorkHours
order by s.shift, s.name
```

Comment: Aren't you just after a `SUM`? Also grouping and aggregating `p.PayRate` makes little sense. Either you want to group on it, or aggregate it (I would suggest the latter).

Comment: @Lamu - Thanks. I removed p.PayRate from the group by, and yeah, I am after a SUM, but I also need to make the multiple rows into one.

Comment: L a r n u, please...

Comment: Sorry, Larnu. Bad eyes.

Comment: *" I also need to make the multiple rows into one."* and that's what grouping will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this what you need. Notice I move the `CASE` expression to be **inside** the `COUNT` to apply to "pivot" (also known as conditional aggregation):

```sql
SELECT s.[name],
       s.shift,
       s.station,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.WorkHours <= 4 THEN 1 END) AS [0-4Hrs],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.WorkHours >= 5 AND t.WorkHours <= 12 THEN 1 END) AS [5-12Hrs],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.WorkHours >= 13 AND t.WorkHours <= 18 THEN 1 END) AS [13-18Hrs],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.WorkHours >= 19 AND t.WorkHours <= 24 THEN 1 END) AS [19-24Hrs],
       SUM(p.PayRate) AS TotalPayAmount
FROM dbo.staff s
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Time] t ON t.FSID = s.FSID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Pay p ON p.Hours = t.WorkHours
WHERE s.[name] = 'John Doe'
GROUP BY s.[name],
         s.shift,
         s.station
ORDER BY s.shift;
```